# Windows Speech Recognition Macros and Relative Paths

Tags: windows, speech-recognition

I'm using WSR Macros with autohotkey to voice-enable some tasks on my development workstation. I currently have the macros and AHK files in separate directories. This generally works well, but it makes it difficult to move the scripts to another machine (or a friend's machine) without changing all the code to point to a new directory. I'd like to keep the paths relative and put the AHK files in the same directory as the macros, but relative paths don't seem to work when executing an external command. For example, this works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<speechMacros>
  <command>
    <listenFor>do a thing</listenFor>
    <run command="C:\MyScripts\dothing.ahk" params=""/>
  </command>
</speechMacros>
```

Any attempt to reference a relative path in the run command seems to fail. I've tried the following:

```
<run command="%CD%\dothing.ahk" params=""/>
<run command=".\dothing.ahk" params=""/>
<run command="dothing.ahk" directory="%CD%" params=""/>
<run command="dothing.ahk" directory="." params=""/>
<run command="dothing.ahk" directory=".\" params=""/>
```

All of which throw an error. Has anybody had any luck getting this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use environment variables in file paths in WSR Macros from time to time, such as:

```
%userprofile%\Downloads
%userprofile%\Documents
```

If these work in AutoHotKey as well, that might provide a way to "genericize" your paths. There are a bunch of environment variables that you could find by searching for "windows environment variables."

-Russ

Comment: I tried the following doing %userprofile%\Documents\dothing.ahk from within the command attribute of the run element (as listed above), but I get the following error, which is what I have been seeing up for my other attempts: <run> executor failure! command %userprofile%\Documents\dothing.ahk params: %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%. Maybe the run command doesn't know how to expand environment variables?